# How do you create a View Pager with dot Indicator with Number?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, viewpagerindicator

Probably many of you Also Me  have problem with creating ViewPager with bottom dots With Number, like this:
[image]

How do you create such an Android ViewPager With Dot and Number?

I am Creating Quiz Application and I Want to Add This Type Of Indicator with Next And Previous Button

Comment: These things are not part of the `ViewPager`. You would have to implement it separately. There are a lot of 3rd party libraries that could help you do that. You should look up for those.

Comment: i make a quiz application and i want to add this type of viewpager

Answer (score -1):

Usually you'll have to build this yourself.

You can also use one of several libraries that does what you need.

For example, there's [this one](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/7813) and also [this one](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/7127) and [this one](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/7900) as well...

You can find many more [here](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/111?sort=created)

Hope this helps.

Comment: But I Want to Add Number in dot indicator